# Ansible - pass different variable to with_items depending on condition

Tags: python, ansible, devops

I've got the following task to create MySQL users and I'm passing `database_staging_users` to `with_items`. I want to pass it `database_production_users` when `vpc_environment == "production"`.

```
- name: Create MySQL users
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    password: "{{ item.password }}"
    priv: "{{ item.privileges }}"
    host: "%"
    state: present
    login_host: "{{ hostvars.localhost.rds_db.instance.endpoint }}"
    login_user: "{{ rds_db_username }}"
    login_password: "{{ rds_db_password }}"
  with_items: database_staging_users
```

Is there a way to do that? I don't want to duplicate the task and use `when:`.

Answer (score 2):

How you use the vars suggests you're not following best practice. `staging` and `production` should be Ansible groups and the users should be defined as group_vars. Then all you pass would be a users list which Ansible automatically picks from the correct group you're running the playbook against.

But to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```
with_items: "{{ database_production_users if vpc_environment == 'production' else database_staging_users }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look at using group vars